# Correct Single pole switch orientation

Tags: electrical

I had two old switches I replaced and purchased some new [eaton switches](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Eaton-Single-Pole-White-Compatible-with-LED-Rocker-Light-Switch/1001438232) from Lowe’s. I installed them similar to the older switches where the ground was on the bottom right. Come to find out the ground should have been in the top left hence the reason when pushed in the top means off (assuming hot wire in is on the bottom). Is there any reason in particular newer switches have the ground up top left and any reason I should switch it to this if I already have it setup to be bottom right?

Comment: These switches are not directional, as there is no "on"/"off" labeling on the switch. You can install them with the ground screw at the top or with the ground screw at the bottom, whichever you prefer.

Comment: @TylerH, there is no "On"/"Off" labeling on the exterior of the switch, but the yoke has plenty of writing indicating which way is up, including the word "top".

Answer (score 3):

General convention is "Up" is on and "Down" is off. However, for a 3-way switch, "light is on" is on and "light is off" is off, and people manage to live with that every day.

I would recommend that you install your standard toggle switch with the lettering readable from the normal, human, upright position. However, as noted in the case of the 3-way switch, people can function when the toggle isn't in the "normal" position, so there's probably little danger and only minor confusion if you install the switch in the "Down" is on position.

Also, it doesn't matter for a simple toggle which wire (power supply vs load) is attached to which screw. Think of the switch as another piece of wire completing the circuit - it doesn't matter which end is "closer" to the power source and which is "closer" to the load, does it? That's all a switch really is - another piece of wire helping to complete the circuit, it's just that this particular piece of wire makes it easy and safe to break the circuit and turn off the flow of power.

Comment: Hey I am more curious why the ground in newer toggle switches is up top rather than below as it use to be. This is what caused all the confusion in the first place is I was assuming ground should be on the bottom similar to recepticles and older light switches. Check out the product link in the question.

Comment: @IrishRedneck because? I dunno... As I understand it, the NEC flip-flopped for a while on whether outlets should be installed with the ground pin up then ground pin down and back. Maybe it's something like that. Maybe one of the electricians will chime in on it. Even better ask that as a specific question.

Comment: @FreeMan That *is* the specific question OP asked above.

Comment: Uh, yeah, I guess you're right. That's what I get for doing too many things at one...

Comment: Just went through Chapter 7 of UL 20 (the governing standard for snap switches), and indeed, that TOP marking is merely a manufacturer's advisory unless the instructions say otherwise

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR This is a free country, install it however you like!**

I doubt (but someone will correct me if I am wrong) if there is any code requirement for location of the ground screw. Keep in mind that with a properly grounded **metal** box and a switch with a metal yoke, you don't even need to use the ground screw! In fact, in addition to 3-way switches, where up & down are meaningless (unless the switch has other "smart" functions like dimming or indicator lights), switches are often installed horizontally instead of vertically - there is no "right" way, just a "traditional" way.

Screws also move around - you could have 3-way switches with travelers on left, travelers on right, travelers on top or travelers on bottom. You could even have one traveler upper-left and one lower-right - but hopefully nobody has made one of those.

Even receptacles are sometimes installed horizontally or "upside down". With receptacles (US style), there is logic to upside down that a partially removed plug will have the ground wire be the first wire hit by something that comes down onto the exposed prongs.